# Setup Sonar Runner + cobertura for multi module projects

Tags: java, xml, maven, sonarqube, cobertura

My Project structure below

```
App XYX
   +- pom.xml
   +-SubfOlder
   +- Module 1
      +- pom.xml 
   +- Module 2
      +- pom.xml 
   +- Module3
      +- pom.xml 
   +- Module4
      +- pom.xml
   .......
   .......
   +- Module10
      +- pom.xml
```

I'm currently using the sonar scanner v2.5.1 as a Jenkins post build task. I'm not sure how to define sonar.sources for all my 10 modules.

I went thru the documentation : https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Advanced+SonarQube+Scanner+Usages
but I don't want to define all the 10 modules one by one. Also what if there are 50+ modules.

Any suggestion how to approach this scenario.Thanks.

Comment: If any of the answers was the right one, consider marking it as correct to help others in need

Answer (score 1):

Use the maven `sonar:sonar` goal. If maven is already set up, than this is much more convenient then using `sonar-project.properties`.

Comment: thanks for looking into it. Yes thats an option. but unfortunately my team wants this way. If its sonar:sonar how can I do coverage for all 10 modules and aggregated the result to a single coverage.xml and pass it it to sonar . thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `sonar.sources` in properties does not recognize wildcards, so the only thing you can do is to list them all manually, comma separated. I have encountered this problem and had about 20 separate projects to write to property line. Here is how my properties look like:

```
sonar.projectKey=xyz
sonar.projectName=xyz
sonar.sources=${WORKSPACE}/client-xyz/,${WORKSPACE}/client-yzx/,${WORKSPACE}/server-xyz/,${WORKSPACE}/server-yzx/,${WORKSPACE}/common-xyz/,${WORKSPACE}/common-yzx/,${WORKSPACE}/zxy-adapter-mq,${WORKSPACE}/zxy-api-yzx,${WORKSPACE}/zxy-common-yzx,${WORKSPACE}/zxy-file-base,${WORKSPACE}/zxy-file-yzx,${WORKSPACE}/zxy-init-yzx,${WORKSPACE}/zxy-jms-yzx,${WORKSPACE}/zxy-messaging-api,${WORKSPACE}/zxy-messaging-in-yzx,${WORKSPACE}/zxy-messaging-out-yzx,${WORKSPACE}/zxy-ws-gen-yzx,${WORKSPACE}/zxy-ws-in-yzx
sonar.java.binaries=**/target/*
sonar.tests=${WORKSPACE}/test-yzx/
sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports
sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin=cobertura
sonar.java.coveragePlugin=cobertura
sonar.verbose=false
sonar.showProfiling=true
sonar.ws.timeout=180
sonar.junit.reportPaths=${WORKSPACE}/test-yzx/junit/
sonar.cobertura.reportPath=${WORKSPACE}/test-yzx/cobertura/coverage.xml
sonar.cobertura.utReportPath=${WORKSPACE}/test-yzx/cobertura/coverage.xml
sonar.java.cobertura.reportPath=${WORKSPACE}/test-yzx/cobertura/coverage.xml
sonar.java.coverage.reportPaths=${WORKSPACE}/test-yzx/cobertura/
sonar.coverage.dtdVerification=false
sonar.scm.disabled=true
```